# OpenVPN Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have a problem to run my client on windows OpenVPN Client, i created my file and when i try to launch it, error is given:

```
Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client1.ovpn:133: < (2.4.4)
```

That is strange because line 133 is a < ca > tag:

```
# script-security 2
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
< ca >
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

And it was generated when i generated a file, so i don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `<ca>`, not `< ca >`.

Comment: Thu Nov 02 11:48:33 2017 ERROR: Endtag </ca> missing Thank you for your answer! But this is what i got, can i send here my file? Is it safe?